# xamarin android intent filter force close (Emulator)

Tags: android, xamarin, intentfilter

I want to use Android Intent-filter to open my Android Page from another Activity. I already search some issues like this, and found some answer, but when i tried in my source, its not work.

I got code to call url link to open my app like this

```
       using (var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://url.com/password/reset/confirm/MQ/46l-4e294a00ac5e43ee8a1b"))
       {
            using (var openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri))
            {
                activity.StartActivity(new Intent(openIntent));
            }
       }
```

And then I want to call my Android page, but always force close. Here is the code

```
    [Activity(Label = "Qrawd")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
   DataScheme = "http",
   DataHost = "url.com",
   Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

public class ResetPasswordPage : Activity
{
    String ui_id, token_id;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var data = Intent.Data;
        String scheme = data.Scheme; // "http"
        String host = data.Host; // "qrawd.com"
        IList<string> param = data.PathSegments;
        String first = param[0]; // "password"
        String second = param[1]; // "reset"
        String confirm = param[2]; // "confirm"
        ui_id = param[3]; // "ui_id"
        token_id = param[4]; // "token"

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ResetPasswordLayout);
    }
}
```

Sometimes there are an errors, sometimes not. Here is the error list :

```
11-10 00:53:57.635 E/InputQueue-JNI( 2619): channel '410c9af0 com.nurosoft/md5e1b91645369ae8dea4dc20d1701359d7.MainActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-10 00:53:57.645 E/InputQueue-JNI( 2619): channel '41220c68 com.nurosoft/md588445bdc4f44543f0c63e6b1da45d3c9.ResetPasswordPage (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-10 00:53:57.694 I/ActivityThread( 2619): Removing dead content provider: settings
11-10 00:53:57.744 E/SurfaceTextureClient( 2619): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
11-10 00:53:57.744 E/SurfaceTextureClient( 2619): queueBuffer (handle=0x19ae4c0) failed (No such device)
11-10 00:53:57.744 D/AndroidRuntime( 2619): Shutting down VM
11-10 00:53:57.744 W/dalvikvm( 2619): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that using 'using' is good practive, but wondering if the Activity lifecycle is closing off the Activity / Intent early, what happens if you just use;

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://url.com/password/reset/confirm/MQ/46l-4e294a00ac5e43ee8a1b");
var openIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
activity.StartActivity(new Intent(openIntent);
```

Comment: I already tried it too sir. Still force close.
When i tried to debug per code, there is no error. It just open the layout for 2-3 seconds and then close.